# How can I save the output of a controller function to a file?

Tags: php, opencart

I searched Google for an answer of the above mentioned question, but I did not find any. This is the 3rd day, and almost one night of searching. The thing is I want to save the output of a controllers function to a file. To be more specific I want to save the output of:

```
public function invoice() {
  //some codes are in here
  $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice.tpl';
  $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

As far as I understood `$this->render()` renders the template that was specified above, and `setOutput()` sends the output of the rendered template to the browser. I am using *Opencart 1.5.6.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does output the content to the browser you can do like below

```
public function invoice() {
    $this->template = 'sale/order_invoice.tpl';
    $out = ob_start();    
    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents('YOUR_FILE_LOCATION', $out);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will give a try tonight and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime :) Good Luck

Comment: Sure :) happy to hear